# "this" is undefined when calling custom lib from asyncThunk created function

Tags: javascript

I created a very simple module that uses this:

```
// log.js
const logger = {

  enabled: false,

  log: (label, value) => {
    let isEnabled = false;
    console.log("BEFORE this");
    try {
      isEnabled = this.enabled;
      console.log("AFTER this");
    }
    catch(err) {
      console.log("ERR calling this ", err);
    }
    if (!isEnabled) {
      return;
    }
    console.log(label, value);
  }
};

export default logger;
```

I want to use this module from an asyncThunk created function:

```
import logger from "./log";

export const dqsLogin = createAsyncThunk(
  "user/login",
  async ({username, password}, thunkAPI) => {

    console.log("BEFORE")
    logger.log("TEST:", "test");
    console.log("AFTER")

    // more code...
  }
);
```

but I'm receiving an exception in the line `isEnabled = this.enabled;`. The error says: "TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'enabled')". The problem is "this" is undefined in the call.

If substituting "this" by "logger" like `isEnabled = logger.enabled;` the library works as intended. But I don't want to make that change. Supposedly the usage of arrow functions in the object solves the any problem with "this".
What is wrong here? Cannot I use "this" in a library to be called by an asyncThunk function?

Comment: Well, sure: you're using an [arrow function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions), so you're telling JS that you explicitly want `this` to be the execution context at declare time, _not_ at runtime. Either write a proper class and instantiate that (definitely the way to go) or use a normal function instead of an arrow function.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The issue you are facing is related to how arrow functions handle the `this` context. Arrow functions do not have their own `this` value; instead, they inherit the `this` value from the surrounding lexical scope (the context in which they were created). In your case, the arrow function inside the `logger` object is inheriting the `this` value of the module, which is `undefined` since the module does not have a `this` context.

To use `this` in the `logger` object, you would need to use a regular function declaration for the `log` method, not an arrow function. Here's the updated code for the `log.js` module:

```js
// log.js
const logger = {
  enabled: false,

  log: function(label, value) { // Use a regular function here, not an arrow function
    let isEnabled = false;
    console.log("BEFORE this");
    try {
      isEnabled = this.enabled;
      console.log("AFTER this");
    } catch(err) {
      console.log("ERR calling this ", err);
    }
    if (!isEnabled) {
      return;
    }
    console.log(label, value);
  }
};

export default logger;
```

By using a **regular function**, this will be bound to the `logger` object, and you'll be able to access the `enabled` property correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Arrow functions don't have the `this` keyword binding.
They also don't have access to `arguments`, etc.
Use this:

```js
log(label, value) {
    // ...some code
}
```

Useful Link: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions

Comment: I didn't really downvote, so I don't know why someone has downvoted this answer, but people don't upvote/downvote based on *speed*, but rather based on ***the quality*** of the content you writing, so if you have a good answer, take your time to write it so someone downvoted your answer based on the quality, probably there's something wrong with the answer, of course, only the downvoter can explain...

Comment: What it is missing, at a quick glance from a programmer who doesn't follow this language and can't comment on the technical merit of the answer, is an explanation of how this answer improves the situation. Why should the asker "Use this:..."? Answering fast isn't the game here. It's answering well.